# How to convert/extract from YYYYMM to year and name of Month? Teradata SQL

Tags: sql, teradata

So i got the date format in YYYYMM (eg. 201910 for Oct 2019), and what I want to have is 2019 and October (in full month name). Year number is easy, but to get the month name is a bit challenging.

In my data `Calendar_Year_Month` is the available field in the format of INT eg. 201910. I firstly converted to STRING and then adding just a random day 01 to become `20191001`, then casting it to DATE format as Year_Month_Date.

```
CAST(Calendar_Year_Month*100+01 AS VARCHAR(8)) AS Year_Month,
CAST(Year_Month AS DATE FORMAT 'YYYYMMDD')AS Year_Month_Date,
```

I tried to use `TO_DATE(Year_Month_Date,'Month') to get the Month name, however, it seems not working.

Any other options to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close:

CAST the int to a date and then apply TO_CHAR:

```
To_Char(Cast((Calendar_Year_Month-190000) * 100 + 1 AS DATE), 'Month') AS cal_month
```

Extracting the year is simple:

```
Calendar_Year_Month/100 as cal_year
```

Comment: Hi @dnoeth, this is working! Thank you so much. I just realise for year 2000 and above, there is additional `1` in front as the stored date code. This is great. Thank you again!

Comment: DATEs are stored using this strange formula: `(year -1900) * 10000 + (month * 100) + day` resulting in 1191001 for 2010-10-01. Only in the last century it was eawy to use 991001=1999-10-01

Comment: yeah! that makes sense now. Thank you again for the solution!

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried:

**1.**

With to_char

```
to_char(Year_Month_Date, 'Month')
```

**2.**

You can always add a **CASE WHEN** for all 12 months if you do not find any simpler solution...

**3.**

With format:

```
Year_Month_Date(format 'MMMM')
```

Or for the combination with year:

```
Year_Month_Date(format 'MMMMBYYYY')
```

Comment: HI @VBoka, I did try your suggestions #1 and #3 and both of them are working. I chose `dnoeth` as the answer is because that I can save below step as I described in my post (per below section): `In my data Calendar_Year_Month is the available field in the format of INT eg. 201910. I firstly converted to STRING and then adding just a random day 01 to become 20191001, then casting it to DATE format as Year_Month_Date.`. For #2 I know this is gonna work but it will make the query quite long that i want to avoid. Hope that makes sense to you. Thank you for your kind help!! Appreciated!

Comment: No it will not. There is more than" accept part" in that link, and all of that that is just a formal part of it. I am looking for the way to make my answers better... To see why this was not helpful to the OP(in this case you). Cheers!

Comment: Hi @VBoka. Once again, thank you so much for the help! Your solution #1 is working but as I said there will be more steps involved to achieve that, and that's why I chose `dnoeth` solution. The solution #3 didn't work in Teradata. I know you offered the solutions first, but when I opened the page again, there are two replies already. So I tried `dnoeth` solution first and it worked well.  I feel sorry to make you feel that way, and I didn't intend to do that.

Comment: #3 does not work ? hmm, I have found that in teradata documentation(FORMAT Phrase and DateTime Formats - https://docs.teradata.com/reader/WurHmDcDf31smikPbo9Mcw/rEp1b71IAI1rxdC3GcBp~g) Shame... Probably it depends on the data parameter it is receiving...

Comment: I have tested this: `SELECT DATE, DATE (FORMAT 'MMMMb,BYYYY')(CHAR(20));` here: http://tunweb.teradata.ws/SQLAssistantWeb/login.aspx?isTrial=1 maybe it will help(for information .. if anything the link to the teradata fiddle...). Cheers.

Comment: FORMAT was intended for reports created from command line BTEQ utility using CLI (low level access to Teradata), in that case Teradata does the formatting. But all other clients like ODBC/JDBC/.NET simply ignore it, still request the original data type and format it based on client side rules. Your link seems to run BTEQ (or something similar) in the background, that'y why it's working. To get the FORMAT you need to finally CAST the expression to a VARCHAR (or simply TRIM it), that's why your 1st solution `to_char` is much easier.

Comment: Regarding *changing the accepted answer*, this simply happens. +1 from me :-)

Comment: Hi @dnoeth nice info. Very nice. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `Calendar_Year_Month` is well-formatted, here's one way to do it:

```sql
SELECT 
  SUBSTRING(CAST(Calendar_Year_Month AS CHAR(6)) FROM 1 FOR 4) AS MyYear -- Extract year
  CASE SUBSTRING(CAST(Calendar_Year_Month AS CHAR(6)) FROM 5 FOR 2) -- Extract month
    WHEN '01' THEN 'January'
    WHEN '02' THEN 'February'
    WHEN '03' THEN 'March'
    WHEN '04' THEN 'April'
    WHEN '05' THEN 'May'
    WHEN '06' THEN 'June'
    WHEN '07' THEN 'July'
    WHEN '08' THEN 'August'
    WHEN '09' THEN 'September'
    WHEN '10' THEN 'October'
    WHEN '11' THEN 'November'
    WHEN '12' THEN 'December'
  END CASE AS MyMonth
FROM MyTable
```

Another option is to try and convert `Calendar_Year_Month` to a `DATE` and use `TO_CHAR()`:

```sql
SELECT 
  CAST(CAST(Calendar_Year_Month AS CHAR(6)) AS DATE FORMAT 'YYYYMM') AS MyDate,
  TO_CHAR(MyDate,'Month') AS MyMonth,
  TO_CHAR(MyDate,'YYYY') AS MyYear
FROM MyTable
```

I don't have a TD system to test, but give it a try and let me know.

Comment: Hi @ravioli, I am trying to avoid `CASE WHEN` to make the code simpler as possible . Thank you anyway!